# Unable to login to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am not able to login into my postgres databse deployed in docker. PFB my docker-compose.yml

```
  discountdb:
    image: postgres
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
  discountdb:
    container_name: discountdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin1234
      - POSTGRES_DB=DiscountDb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

When I am trying to create server from pgAdmin4, I am getting the following error

[image]

Following is the db logs

[image]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my postgres_data volume. I removed the volume using the command

```
docker volume rm -f discountdb
```

then ran the docker-compose again which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables you set are only used if Postgres can't find an existing database when then container starts.

Since you map a docker volume to `/var/lib/postgresql/data/`, chances are that you already have a database with existing users defined.

Try removing the volume mapping, so you're sure that Postgres creates a fresh database. If that solves it, then you have two options:

1. If you don't need the data in the volume, you can delete the postgres_data volume so Postgres creates a new database
2. If you need the data, you need to find out what userid/password you need to use to access the existing database in the volume

Comment: I have installed postgres in my system before but not as a docker image. Dose that making this issue because password for that instance was different

Comment: There was some issue with my volume. I am not sure what happened though. Anyway, recreating that volume resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong here but the POSTGRES_PASSWORD is taken into account the first time you start the container I mean when your postgres_data folder is still empty. If you changed the password but postgres_data is not empty the new password is ignored, you must log in with the first one.

Comment: I took the image from the docker hub. This is my first image and I jever changed the password